# Retrieve variable from functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am using the following function to check for blacklisted email domains on BuddyPress registration.....

```
function bp_as_restrict_signup_domains( $email_blacklist_result ) {

    $banned = array(
        'test.com', 
        'spammer.com'
    );
    $error = 'Your email domain has been the source of spam. Please use another email address.';

    $email = $email_blacklist_result['user_email']; 
    $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));
    if ( in_array($domain, $banned))
    {
        $email_blacklist_result['errors']->add('user_email', __($error, 'bp-restrict-email-domains' ) );
    };
    return $email_blacklist_result;
}
add_filter( 'bp_core_validate_user_signup', 'bp_as_restrict_signup_domains' );
```

What I would like to do is provide the user with some feedback that their email has been rejected,  how can I add a variable to this function that I can retrieve in the template?

Something like `$bl_result = blacklisted`?

Answer (score 0):

In your register template, you should see:

```
<?php do_action( 'template_notices' ); ?>
```

You should be able to send messages to it like so:

```
if ( in_array($domain, $banned))
{
    $email_blacklist_result['errors']->add('user_email', __($error, 'bp-restrict-email-domains' ) );
    bp_core_add_message( 'Your email has been rejected' );
};
```